# How do I downgrade Firefox 56 to 52esr?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, downgrade

Currently I am running FF56 on Ubuntu 16.04. Despite the cool new stuff in FF57, I can't update because some extensions I regularly use won't be compatible, and there are no similar compatible extensions available.

But I do want to keep up on security updates. I hate to go back to FF52, but the only option I can see is to downgrade FF56 to FF52esr. The file available from Mozilla for 32-bit en-US is "firefox-52.5.0esr.tar.bz2".

I realize there are other questions that deal with handling installations using this kind of archive, however I was hoping someone could write a procedure for this specific situation, as it may be commonly needed for those wishing to retain FF57 incompatible extensions.

Comment: why not stay with v56?

Comment: @ravery To keep up to date with future security updates, since I don't know the update future of some extensions.

Comment: The "kind of archive" is similar to ZIP or RAR. You don't install that file, you install its contents by extracting  it then following instructions either from the website or some "readme" file inside. Too much trouble, I wager, just to keep using extensions that don't work in newer version for a reason.